# SSIS File System Task fails without error

Tags: ssis

I am building a simple Integration Services project that reads a "pending" directory of CSV files, loads each one into a staging table, and moves the file to a "completed" or "failed" directory depending on whether it was loaded successfully or not. The locations of the "completed" and "failed" directories are set in the project parameters.

The problem is, the "move to failed directory" task never executes, even though all the tasks leading up to it execute successfully. The frustrating thing is that no error message is produced. I have tried setting a breakpoint on the task's event handlers but the breakpoints are never hit. It is like the task is not there at all (I have checked that the `Disabled` property was not inadvertently set on the task but it's not).

It is strange because the "move to completed" task works fine and both tasks are identical save for the directory they write to. Both directories exist and have the same access permissions, though I imagine there would be some kind of error if it were a permissions problem.

[image: SSIS flow]

In the diagram above, it is the `MoveToFailed` task on the right-hand side that is not working. It can be reached in a number of ways-- a duplicate file or unknown file, or a file containing invalid records. The task does not execute regardless of how it is called.

Comment: Can you spare a screenshot of the control flow?

Comment: Excellent. So when these bad things happen, does the package end with an error or are they logical errors and thus the package should do something? I see the expression on GetValidInvalidRecordCount which makes me think that path is a logical error. But the MarkInvalidFile and the other script task look like they are constrained to success only.

Comment: @billinkc: No, there is no error at all; that is the crazy thing. If, for example, I place a file with a duplicate name in the "pending" directory and execute the package in Visual Studio, the green tick marks appear beside the `GetBatchNumber` and `MarkDuplicate` tasks but no mark (green or red) will appear beside `MoveToFailed` and the output window will say the package ran successfully. Like I said, it's like the task simply isn't there!

Comment: If you put a duplicate file out there and reroute the precedent constraint from `GetBatchNumber` directly to `MoveToFailed`, does the file get moved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the precedence constraints in to MoveToFailed so they are in the 'Logical OR' mode.
Pick one of the constraints in to that component and right-click, choose 'Edit' There is a radio button at the bottom marked 'Logical OR. One constraint must evaluate to True'.

Comment: MarkDuplicate is completing successfully and has no Expression on the precedent constraint. There's nothing for them to OR on that constraint. Am you reading it differently?

Comment: The way you have it written all three of the precedence constraints leading into that task must be true before the task will execute. If you change it like I explained then the task will execute when any one of the precedence constraints is true.

Comment: Yes, it was the precedence constraints. A rookie mistake on my part; the ETL/EAI tool I'm most familiar with triggers a task on any input (OR).